# about spring-boot life cycle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans

If bean implements InitializingBean and BeanPostProcessor interface
why afterPropertiesSet first execute?
 Should execute postProcessBeforeInitialization or postProcessAfterInitialization?

use spring-boot version:1.5.2

I would be grateful if there were more detailed instructions!thank you!